# AndroidRestart Activity from PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences

I declared my `PreferenceFragment` within a `SettingsActivity` like this

```
public class ChordsSettings extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, new MyPreferenceFragment())
            .commit();
}

public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings_preferences);
    }
}
}
```

I did it like this and didn't create a Fragment on top of the `MainActivity` because I need to be able to use the back button to get from the `SettingsActivity` to the `MainActivity` and this seamed like the only way to go to achieve that.

**I need to restart my `MainActivity` once the preferences changed.**

I tried sending a `Broadcast` from the `preferenceFragment` but `sendBroadcast()` cannot be used from a static context. Is there any other way I can achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried calling the activity itself using intent and finish the previous activity?

Comment: Yes, but I also need to restart it. because otherwise when I go back from `SettingsActivity` the app will close

Comment: I think you can do it like this. When you click the button from the MainActivity you should finish the acivity and open settings activity. And when you click accept button to save preferences, you should finish SettingsActivity and start the MainActivity.

Comment: Now you may think what happen if the user don't want to change their settings and press back button. Well, you should override onBackPressed and add an intent where it finish the SettingsActivity and calls the MainActivity.

Comment: If you made up your mind and want the implementation i can show you.

Comment: sure I understand. this seams promising. please show me an implementation.

Comment: I already post the implementation below. Be sure to check it and I hope it helps you in some way. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your MainActivity should probably look like this. Note that when btnGoToSetting is clicked finish() method is called. This is for closing the currrent Activity.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnGoToSetting;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnGoToSetting = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnGoToSetting);
        btnGoToSetting.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**SettingsActivity.java**

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnSavePreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        btnSavePreferences = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSavePreferences);
        btnSavePreferences.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Here is where you save all your preferences
                yourSaveFunction();
                finish();
                Intent intent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
        Intent intent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

*Note : There is another way to resfresh you data in MainActivity by making your data asynchronous so that everytime the data changes it will be refresh automatically.*

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Please tell me more about Asynchronous data. Could be interesting too.

Comment: @Daniele It depends on what type of database you are using. Certain database provide a method that will make your data scnychronous. What type of database did you use?

Comment: I'm not using any database it's all stored locally. I'm using a List

Comment: @Daniele How do you store the database locally? You are using SQLite?

Comment: I'm not using any database at all. all my data is kept in the apk itself

Comment: You mean you store it in the local variables only?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149415/discussion-between-daniele-and-umarzaii).